# Share Point 2008 Configuration in Windows 7 System Share Point server.exe Extraction Issue?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need **SharePoint** server 2008 in my development system. So I referred the Microsoft documents and started to configure.

I Completed the required things in my Windows 7 x64 system. And then I referred this link to **SharePointServer.exe** extraction process,

> Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZZkgu0BiGk

but those people worked, but me not able to understand what is the issue.
I attached Screenshot, refer it and give me the solution....

Error Screen Shot:

[image: Screen Shot]

My Configuration is referred from this links,

1. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/373724/SharePoint-Installation-on-Windows
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee554869(v%3Doffice.14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove .exe in your comment text. It will work.

Old Comment Text : **C:SharePointServer.exe /extract:C:\Sharepoint**

New Comment Text : **C:SharePointServer /extract:C:\Sharepoint**